# Problem with multidimensional interpolation: "Data point {0,0} contains abscissa 0, which is not a real number"

Tags: warning-messages, interpolation, data

I'm trying to do a multidimensional interpolation. For simplicity, say I have the following array:

```
{{{a,b},c},{{d,e},f},{{g,h},i}}
```

This means that I have a two-variable function $F(x,y)$ such that $F(a,b)=c$, $F(d,e)=f$ and $F(g,h)=i$. The Mathematica documentation for `Interpolation` has an example of this type, so it should work; indeed, it works with a very simple example like

```
{{{1,2},3},{{4,5},6},{{7,8},9}}
```

Obviously, my table is much bigger and does not consist purely of natural numbers. (It does consist entirely of positive real numbers, so there should be no funky complex-number business.)

When I try to graph the interpolation, I get the following message:

> `Interpolation: Data point {0,0} contains abscissa 0, which is not a real number.`

I find that funny, because 0 obviously *is* a real number. Aside from that, however, I don't understand what the message is trying to tell me.

- First, the interpolation is a two-variable function, so shouldn't that read `(0,0,0)` (for example) rather than `(0,0)`?
- Second, why does it say 0 isn't a real number?
- Third, why is having abscissa 0 a problem?

Here's how I'm building my table:

[image]

This works well; when I look at (a subset of) the resulting data, it looks exactly the way I expect it to:

[image]

But this is what happens if I try to do something with the interpolation:

[image]

Comment: Please post code that can be copied/pasted so your result can be reproduced. Look at `InputForm@cpy01` perhaps you have strings in your data.

Comment: You could first check all the values in cpy1 for real numbers via:  MemberQ[Internal`RealValuedNumericQ /@ (Flatten@cpy1), False]  which will return True if any are not.

Comment: Just checked; no strings, just numbers. But there was an error in the way I was constructing `cpy01` and some rows had no data. Thanks for making me look at the full dats carefully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occured because I had no data in some of the rows of `cpy01` due to my `For` loop being wrong. I should have written `(v-1)U+u` instead of `(v-1)V+u`.

Everything works just fine now. Thanks to those who commented on my original post for making me look at my data more closely, which revealed the "holes" in the data, which in turn made me notice that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something wrong with your data. Check it inside Mathematica.

The procedure you describe is working as the following example shows:

We first create some data in the requested format:

```
d = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
d = {#, Total[#]} & /@ d;
```

Then we interpolate it and plot the resulting function:

```
fun = Interpolation[d, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot3D[fun[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Just checked; the data is just numbers, so it's fine. But there was an error in the way I was constructing `cpy01` and some rows of the array had no data. Thanks!